# Proper way to create .env file for the project

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have Node.js project, where I want to have `.env` file with variables. I created one, but when inside project file I log to console `process.env` it logmy global npm variables, and not created in root folder file. What I did wrong?

Comment: Node doesn't read `.env` files automatically.  You'll need to include a library to do it like [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: agree with @zero298 in case of variable which are static. .env file will be picked up when you are using docker/container for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended in a comment, use a package such as [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

1. Install using

```sh
npm install dotenv

# or with Yarn 
yarn add dotenv
```

2. In the entrypoint of your application, add the following line to load the library and your environment variables:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```